How to know CSS property webkit-line-clamp is active with JS?
i was wondering if there is any way to know when the webkit-line-clamp is activated to use in an conditional.
For example I want to show the Show more text but only if the clamp is being applied.
<div class="clamped-text" id="text-clamp">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
</div>

<span class="show-more">Show more</span>

.clamped-text {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    width: 300px;
}

.show-more {
   display: none;
}

.show-more.clamped {
  display: block
}

I am currently using JS to slice the text and show/hide the content, without using the clamp

In most situations, it would probably suffice to watch for overflow on the clamped element, like this:
const hasOverflow = ({
  clientWidth,
  clientHeight,
  scrollWidth,
  scrollHeight,
}) => scrollHeight > clientHeight || scrollWidth > clientWidth;

const clampedText = document.querySelector('.clamped-text');
const showMore = document.querySelector('.show-more');

const setShowMoreState = () =>
  showMore.classList.toggle('clamped', hasOverflow(clampedText));

const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(setShowMoreState);

resizeObserver.observe(clampedText);


Why scrollWidth > clientWidth?

@imhvost Good question. Honestly, I don't know whether it's needed (or desirable). If I were implementing this, I'd want to test with and without it on various browsers and devices. But I think the basic approach is the right idea: watch for overflow on the clamped element.
